# Overloaded template method not resolved as expected

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> struct CSizex {
};

struct CSize : public CSizex<int> 
{
};

struct Logger
{
    template <typename T> 
    Logger& operator<< (T& value)
    {
        return *this << const_cast<const T & >(value);
    }

    template <typename T> Logger& operator<<(const CSizex<T>& size)
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCSIG__;
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T> 
    Logger& operator<< (const T& value)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value || std::is_integral<T>::value || std::is_enum<T>::value, "This method is only meant for arithmetic types");
        std::cout << __FUNCSIG__;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CSize size;
    Logger() << CSize();
    return 0;
}
```

When I do this:

```
Logger() << CSize();
```

the compiler is trying to instantiate `Logger& operator<<(const T& value)` overload, which, of course, fails with `static_assert`. Why isn't `Logger& operator<<(const CSizex<T>& size)`  considered a better match? How can I implement what I want?

Comment: What's the difference between `CSize` and `CSizex`? That seems relevant.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: sorry, that's a typo. Fixed.

Comment: what is the body of `operator<<(const CSizex<T>& size)` ?

Comment: @PiotrS.: nothing more than `return *this;`. Edited the question to reflect that. GCC 4.9.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08f4a3066e2fe850

Comment: @PiotrS.: same error with MSVC 2013.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I don't believe you have presented the complete example that triggers the error

Comment: @PiotrS.: I've figured out what triggers the problem. Please see the updated code in the question. I think I understand why it works the way it does, but how can I achieve what I want? Short of `enable_if` on the `const T&` overload?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe it's not `Logger() << CSizex<int>();` that fails, but `Logger() << CSize();`, and this is because `const T&` is a better match than `const CSizex<T>&` (because `CSize` only derives from `CSizex<int>`). Now partial ordering is not taken into consideration, because the latter requires an upcast to base class. Maybe you want to have `using CSize = CSizex<int>;` ? Then you will get the expected result.

Comment: @PiotrS.: Right, I've edited some parts of the question but forgot the others. I would get the expected result with `typedef` as well as `using`, but there's a reason `CSize` is declared the way it is. It has to be a sublcass.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe how about [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14ba4932d5bc6576) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a fact, `const CSizex<T>&` is an *exact* match as it is an identity conversion; [over.ics.ref]/1:

> When a parameter of reference type binds directly to an argument
>   expression, the implicit conversion sequence is the identity
>   conversion, unless the argument expression has a type that is a
>   derived class of the parameter type, in which case the implicit
>   conversion sequence is a derived-to-base Conversion (13.3.3.1).

The specialization instantiated from the template that causes the error is also an exact match:
[over.ics.user]/4:

> A conversion of an expression of class type to the same class type is
>   given Exact Match rank, and a conversion of an expression of class
>   type to a base class of that type is given Conversion rank, in spite
>   of the fact that a copy/move constructor (i.e., a user-defined
>   conversion function) is called for those cases.

However, the first template is more specialized than the second. After removing references and cv-qualifiers from the parameters and argument types of both the original and the transformed templates we then, for a unique type `Unique`, deduce the argument of the transformed template against the parameter of the original template of the other template: `Unique` is deduced against `CSizex<T>`, which yields a deduction failure (since `Unique` is no specialization of `CSizex`), while `CSizex<Unique>` deduced against `T` would be successful (with `T` being `CSizex<Unique>` itself). So the first template is more specialized and should thus be selected by partial ordering.
 [Clang compiles this correctly.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6be39f4fa68f360f) So does [GCC 4.9.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf8aea8247cb9a98). Perhaps you reduced your problem to a code that does not reflect the mistake anymore.

---

#### Updated:

Now, we consider

```
template <typename T>
Logger& operator<<(const CSizex<T>& size); // #1

template <typename T> 
Logger& operator<< (const T& value);       // #2
```

For #2, the argument is deduced as `CSize` so the parameter is `CSize const&`, while for #1 the parameter of the specialization is `CSize<int> const&`.
Overload resolution clearly states in the above quote:

> When a parameter of reference type binds directly to an argument
>   expression, the implicit conversion sequence is the identity
>   conversion, unless the argument expression has a type that is a
>   derived class of the parameter type, in which case the implicit
>   conversion sequence is a derived-to-base Conversion (13.3.3.1).

... that the conversion is an identity conversion for #2 but a derived-to-base conversion for #1. It is not hard to see that #2 is selected due to the better rank, [over.best.ics]/6:

> A derived-to-base Conversion has Conversion rank (13.3.3.1.1).

... and identity conversions have Exact Match rank.
Basically it should suffice to move the condition of the static assertion into `enable_if`:

```
struct Logger
{
    template <typename T>
    Logger& operator<<(const CSizex<T>& size)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value
                         || std::is_integral<T>::value 
                         || std::is_enum<T>::value, Logger&>::type
    operator<<(const T& value)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        return *this;
    }
};
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/Ur4zVu).

Comment: Same error in MSVC 2013, I don't think it's a compiler bug.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe ... you use VC++ and don't believe in compiler bugs with overload resolution and templates?

Comment: @Columbo: I use VC++ for Windows, GCC 4.9 for Android, GCC 4.8 for Linux and clang for Mac OS X. And I don't believe in compiler bugs in such basic functionality.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe GCC 4.9.0 compiles this. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf8aea8247cb9a98

Comment: @VioletGiraffe the code you posted compiles fine in all: GCC 4.9, clang and VS 2013, so kindly post the exact code that triggers the error

Comment: @PiotrS.: this is my main project, to compile the complete `Logger` class, I'd need to post quite a few other classes. I have no idea what's the dramatic difference between the actual code and the snippet I've posted. let me see...

Comment: @VioletGiraffe the error messages should guide you directly to the place which tries to instantiate the member function causing assertion failure

Comment: @Angew I elaborated on the partial ordering a bit, in case that answers the question in the comment you deleted.

Comment: I have indeed reduced the code incorrectly. Can you please take a look at the updated code in the question? `CSize` declaration is what has changed.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Somehow trivial, but I added an example with `enable_if` - will it work for you?

Comment: It works, that's the idea I've had as well. I was hoping for a better solution.